# Luamacros & Stream Deck / macropads not working in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, lua, macros, visual-studio-2017

I want useful functions, like build, save all, debug etc - to be activated by a single key press on a second keyboard when using Visual Studio.

I've setup Luamacros and it's working well in all applications - as a test I've remapped my second keyboard z to enter, and space to enter as well. In, say, Sublime Text I press z on my second kyboard and it outputs Enter. I press space on my second keyboard - and it outputs enter:

```
lmc_device_set_name('mykeyboard','mycode')
lmc_print_devices()

lmc_set_handler('mykeyboard', function(button,direction)
  if (direction == 1) then return end
  if (button == 90) then
    lmc_send_keys('{ENTER}', 50)

    elseif (button == 32) then
    lmc_send_keys('{ENTER}', 50)


  end
end
)
```

There's one exception - Visual Studio 2017 Community. In that program the second keyboard just functions as a normal keyboard - z types z.

I'm also testing an Elgato Stream Deck - and it too works in all applications except Visual Studio as well.

I can find no discussion of these products and Visual Studio specifically online apart from a single forum post talking about symbols being incorrectly added - which isn't relevant.

Does VS have some kind of second keyboard blocker?

Do we know why macropads don't work in Visual Studio - and if there's a way to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I think this might be because I run Visual Studio as administrator and not Stream Deck. Though I have since returned the product so can no longer test this hypothesis.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about Luamacros, but if you want to macro text into an application running in Administrator context with the Stream Deck you have to close the management software and restart it as Administrator.

I had the same problem with some admin command prompt and Visual Studio 2017 macros on Windows 10 using the 4.0.0.9742 Stream Deck software, now it works like a charm.

Comment: I returned the item so can no longer test it - but I think you might be right that it was because the app wasn't running as Administrator.

Comment: I had this issue with my DIY macro pad. Can confirm that before running Lua macros as administrator, Visual Studio did not pick up on the commands.